# Making Xinput map-to-output permanent

Tags: autostart

I have a configuration with 2 touch screens that I want to run independently.

When I run these commands from the command line:

`$ xinput map-to-output "input ID" "Output Device"`

It works fine.

When I try to make the change permanent (at boot) by either putting those commands in ./˜profile or by adding it to .xsessionrc:

`echo xinput map-to-output "input ID" "Output Device" >> ~/.xsessionrc`

It doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `.xsessionrc` runs too early so I added `sleep 4` (it works fine for me, you can change it)

```
sleep 4 && xinput map-to-output 'input name/ID' "Display" &
```

Don`t forget `&` at the end of line otherwise your system will just stuck for sleep time without any effect.

Comment: It works only until the point, where you change your monitor configuration: attach new monitor, close laptop lid, ... Any ideas now to conquer this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestion to run xinput as Startup Applications in the desktop environment:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1907639#p1907639

```
Name: Thinkpad Touchscreen Fix
Command: xinput map-to-output 15 LVDS-1
Comment: Remap touchscreen to Thinkpad monitor
Delay: 41
```

This also uses a delay.

Comment: It works only until the point, where you change your monitor configuration: attach new monitor, close laptop lid, ... Any ideas now to conquer this?

Answer (score 0):

I've added my xinput commands to the end of /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart (Raspberry Pi desktop environment)

```
xinput map-to-output 8 HDMI-1
```